# Inserting CSS-linked HTML in HTML page code via JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do not have access to the HTML of the pages (they are program-built dynamically).
I do have access to the JS page it is linked to.

For example I can do somethin like this and it works:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('main_co');
    var i=1;
    var val="";

  while(i<=1)
    {  if(!document.getElementById('timedrpact01'+i))
        {
            var ele = document.createElement("div");  ele.setAttribute("id","timedrpact01"+i);
            ele.setAttribute("class","inner");

            ele.innerHTML=" Hi there!" ;

            output.appendChild(ele);
```

I would like to use this basis insert a button that would allow to switch from one CSS set (there are several files invoked) to another _another path.

Many thanks

Comment: did you searched for css through javascript?

Comment: 'been looking all over..

Answer (score 0):

The external stylesheets are referenced using `link`, as in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/path-to-css">
```

So, get hold of the appropriate `link` element using:

```
var css = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0];
```

Here, we got hold of the first `link` available by specifying the `[0]` index.

Then, overwrite the `href` attribute to point it to the new path.

```
css.setAttribute("href", "http://example.com/path-to-css");
```

Comment: Thanks! OOps I need q few more things:

Comment: Thanks! OOps I need q few more things: there are several css lines:  <link media="all" href="../file01.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link media="all" href="../file02.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link media="all" href="../file03.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link media="all" href="../file04.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: If I read well, I should: 1:insert a new set of "link" (one for each css file) _but I don't know how to script this. 2:then I would need to have a button that would fire this new set _or revert to the previous one_ 3: Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Identify the order and then use the appropriate index. For button click, use a click handler to run the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.onload=function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('main_co');
    var i=1;
    var val="";
    //switch all the href's to another path
    var switchStyleSheet = function() {
      var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
      for(var i=0; lkC = links.length; i < lkC; i++)
         links[0].href = links[0].href.replace('path_to_file', '_path_to_file');
    };

   while(i<=1) //while is not required here, if i is 1
   {  
      if(!document.getElementById('timedrpact01'+i)) {
        var ele = document.createElement("div");  ele.setAttribute("id","timedrpact01"+i);
        ele.setAttribute("class","inner");
        ele.innerHTML=" Hi there!" ;
        var button = document.createElement('button');

        if(button.addEventListener) {
          button.addEventListener('click', switchStyleSheet);
        }
        else { 
          button.attachEvent('click', switchStyleSheet);
        }

        output.appendChild(button);
        output.appendChild(ele);
      }
   }
 }
```