# Possible to add SlideMenu to hybrid Cordova App?

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to know if it is possibe to add elements such as Feinstein's Slidemenu
 to a hybrid app created with Cordova.
I 've managed to buid an app wich works "ok" but navigation is so, so .
A nice slider woud make it much easier to navigate.
I would like the slider to lead to the main parts of the mini-site in the www folder. If the slider was always available whatever the page of the minisite being displayed that would be perfect.
I also need to konw how and where to edit the lnks that would be displayed on the slider.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it makes no sense to add the actual Android's Java code as plugin for that purpose. There are though many CSS & JS frameworks that provide that kind of functionality. If I understood correctly, what you want is pretty much what at least Onsen UI has readily available [here](http://onsen.io/guide/getting_started.html) (see the example called "Sliding menu"). With Onsen UI you can also combine many of those basic layouts so that you would for example have sliding menu and the tab bar on bottom.

Also looked into ionic framework which seems to have same kind of functionality [available](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/) out-of-box.

Comment: Just looked into it. Looks excellent!
One question though: in the index.html file you can modify the menu that links to the page displayed on teh right. These links originaly either point to page1.htm or page2.html. However do they just change the name's tite or acually load new pages? I have not been able to locate those pages, and they shoud be in the smae directory since there is no indication ot the contrary...

Comment: I'm glad it was what you were looking for! Since I noticed that you haven't accepted any answer for [your first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995243/inserting-css-linked-html-in-html-page-code-via-js), it may be that you aren't familiar with the concept of accepting answer to your question.If so you can read more about accepting an answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It yields reputation for both questioner and respondent. Of course, if you feel that answers don't answer your question, you aren't required to accept.

Comment: Can you answer my follwup question or do I have to post it separately?

Comment: Heh, that is why we try to politely invite questioners to do so if they seem to be happy with answer :) I assume you used the sliding menu from Onsen UI, right? The page1.html (and page2.html) is actually inside the same index.html file. The _<ons-template id="page1.html">_ is where it starts from. Can you find those?

Comment: very UseFul option for Quick Development for Hybrid app developers .